# How to add a column with a stock symbol to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I try to pull stocks quotations using a pandas_datareader. Here is a code I am using:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

stocks=['asb.pl','plw.pl','ten.pl']

df = pd.concat([web.DataReader(stock,'stooq')[:1] for stock in stocks]).reset_index()
```

The result of print(df) looks like this:

```
        Date    Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
0 2020-04-30    3.37    3.39    3.28    3.28  128860
1 2020-04-30  449.50  449.50  415.00  425.00   43509
2 2020-04-30  440.00  444.00  410.50  419.50   23920
```

How can I add a stock symbol in a first column so the result would look like this:

```
   Symbol  Date          Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
0  asb.pl  2020-04-30    3.37    3.39    3.28    3.28  128860
1  plw.pl  2020-04-30  449.50  449.50  415.00  425.00   43509
2  ten.pl  2020-04-30  440.00  444.00  410.50  419.50   23920
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I did a lot of research bofore asking.  However I did not figured out that I have to concatenate to quotations data frame a series with symbols as Arne suggested below.

Comment: Right, but can you be more specific about what the issue is/was?

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve]. `start` and `end` are undefined.

Comment: Issue/problem was that I wanted to add to a result a stock symbol.  With the code I was using I receive only dates, Close, Open, High,Low, Volume.

Comment: That is the goal or objective, not a specific issue...

Comment: With start and end, that's my fault, I should not show them in a code. They are not working with a stooq data source anyway so they are not needed. My goal was to pull a last quotation so I used indexing.

Comment: _They are not working with a stooq data source anyway so they are not needed._ I've been playing around with this particular question, trying to familiarize myself with pandas-datareader, and found that you can use `pandas_datareader.get_data_stooq` which will handle the date range correctly. I'll try to have an answer posted today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same function as for creating your DataFrame: `pd.concat()`. It takes as its first argument a list of pandas Series or DataFrames to concatenate, so `stocks` should be converted to a Series first. You can do that with `pd.Series()`, which additionally takes a `name` argument that you can use to specify what is going to be the column name. Finally, pass `axis=1` to `pd.concat()` to make it a concatenation along the columns.

```py
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(stocks, name='Symbol'), df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Adding a series with symbols and concatenating with stocks quotations work pefrect. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just do `df["Symbol"] = stocks` ?

Comment: @AMC I assumed OP wanted this as the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the way in which you get the data?

```py
import datetime as dt

import pandas_datareader as pdr

stocks = ['asb.pl', 'plw.pl', 'ten.pl']

end = dt.datetime.now()

start = end - dt.timedelta(days=2)
print(start, end="\n\n")

df = pdr.get_data_stooq(symbols=stocks, start=start, end=end).stack("Symbols")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
2020-04-29 17:21:12.690845

Attributes           Close    High      Low    Open  Volume
Date       Symbols                                         
2020-04-30 asb.pl     3.28    3.39    3.280    3.37  128860
           plw.pl   425.00  449.50  415.000  449.50   43509
           ten.pl   419.50  444.00  410.500  440.00   23920
2020-04-29 asb.pl     3.32    3.38    3.245    3.25  144000
           plw.pl   449.50  453.00  440.500  441.00   13464
           ten.pl   431.00  435.00  415.500  416.50   24347
```

I imagine that this is also far more efficient.

Comment: My end goal is to load quotations to db. Previous solutions give me the output which is easier to load to db (all headers in the same row, repeated dates). Thanks for this suggestion, when I was reading pandas datareader documentation I didn't find "get_data_stooq" method.

Comment: @uriahpete What are you using to load the data? There might be a way to improve the format.

Comment: I am using SQLAlchemy and create_engine method, then I am loading data using pandas to_sql method. I managed to succesfully load data.